# How to call POST method in .NET CORE MVC directly from Razor View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to call my method from controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendPhoneVerificationCode() 
{
  // ...code
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(ConfirmPhoneNumber));
}
```

from my Index.cshtml view using button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="button">Send Verification Phone Code</button>
```

how can I do this?

Comment: if my answer work for you please vote up and mark it as accepted.  thank you

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be

```
@page // important

<form method="POST">
   <input type="submit" asp-page-handler="SendPhoneVerificationCode" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And in your code behind.

```
public IActionResult SendPhoneVerificationCode() 
{
   return RedirectToPage("./ConfirmPhoneNumber");
}
```

I would recommend you use razor page without mixing with mvc controller

You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 3):

You could use tag helper in ASP.Net Core MVC:

```
<form asp-action="SendPhoneVerificationCode" asp-controller="YourControllerName">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="button">Send Verification Phone Code</button>
</form>
```

Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2

You could also use ajax to call the method like below:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="post()" name="button">Send Verification Phone Code</button>

@section Scripts{ 
<script>
    function post() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ABC/SendPhoneVerificationCode",
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = "/ABC/ConfirmPhoneNumber"
    }
        })        
    }
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I mis-read the question and went under the assumption that the op was using Razor pages. Instead of deleting the answer I posted for Razor Pages, I'll leave it in case it helps anybody.

**Razor Pages**

You need to wrap your button inside of a `<form>` tag. You can use some built in [.net core tag helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to specify what method you want to call once the form gets submitted. Make sure your button has the `type="submit"`. That tells the form that whenever it's clicked, go ahead and make a post request to that handler.

```
<form asp-page-handler="SendPhoneVerificationCode" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="button">Send Verification Phone Code</button>
</form>
```

**MVC**

Replace `asp-page-handler` with `asp-action`.

```
<form asp-action="SendPhoneVerificationCode" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="button">Send Verification Phone Code</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This redirect me to page: `https://localhost:5000/Manage/Index?handler=SendPhoneVerificationCode`

Comment: @DiPix Sorry. I misunderstood you and assumed you were using Razor Pages. I've updated my answer. See if that works.

Comment: It was my mistake, I didn't realized that MVC != Razor Pages ;) 
One more question, how can I pass there some values or even object? Is it possible?

Comment: `<button type="submit" name="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ConfirmPhoneNumber", "Manage")'">Send Verification Phone Code</button>` is this is correct way to call GET method? Or it's hack? :D

Answer (score 0):

HttpPost is a bit tricky. I usually use HttpGet for referring to any controller.

Your Controller...

```
    [HttpGet("~/Somthing")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendPhoneVerificationCode() 
    {
    // ...code
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(ConfirmPhoneNumber));
    }
```

In your razor Component...

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="@($"Somthing")" target="_blank">Send Verification Phone Code</a>
```