# How do I use post method to display a content in ASP.net core MVC

Tags: c#, post, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Im fairly new to ASP.net programming, but I still am familiar with C# and C languages. I was initially taught how to navigate around ASP.net Razor pages. It was simple and easy to follow through. But for my final project, I went on and did a ASP.net core MVC page. Till now it is fine and working (working principle was similar), except the backend part. In razor pages, the pages were together, index.cshtml and index.cshtml.cs were in one place, but in MVC its not the case. Im facing difficulty understanding how to use `method="post"` in my page.

My razor view page code:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Lorem Ipsum Generator";
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<style>
    body {
        /* Margin bottom by footer height */
        margin-bottom: 60px;
        font-family: Kalam, cursive;
    }

    nav {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #a8e6cf, #dcedc1, #ffd3b6, #ffaaa5, #ff8b94);
        background-size: 200% 200%;
        animation: rainbow 10s alternate infinite;
    }
    .JK {
        padding: 15px 25px;
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #04AA6D;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 15px;
        box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
    }
    .JK:hover {
        background-color: #3e8e41
    }
    .JK:active {
        background-color: #3e8e41;
        box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
        transform: translateY(4px);
    }
</style>

<html>
<body class="text-center">
    <form method="post">
        <h1 style="font-size:26px;">Lorem Ipsum Generator</h1>
        <p>At this page, You will get to generate Lorem Ipsum text, at your desired size and format. Enjoy!</p>
        <p>Enter Number of words to generate: <input id="wordx" type="text" value="10" /></p>
        <p>Enter Number of paragraphs to generate: <input id="parax" type="text" value="2" /></p>
        <p>Include Data and time at the end of the list? (Proxy is allowed!)  <input type="radio" id="Y" name="Dt" />Yes    <input type="radio" id="N" name="Dt" checked="checked" />No</p>
        <p>If you have selected the option "Yes", Please choose a specific time and date: <input type="datetime-local" id="datetimex" /></p>
        <p>Do you want the generator to start with "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" (Check the box, only if you want): <input type="checkbox" id="startx" />Yes</p>
        <p><input type="submit" class="JK" value="Generate!" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I viewed this page: [How to call POST method in .NET CORE MVC directly from Razor View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58015982/how-to-call-post-method-in-net-core-mvc-directly-from-razor-view) for a solution, but it didn't workout as thought. I am using this Lorem Lpsum generator: https://github.com/EdCharbeneau/Prototyping

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: It's fairly simple, just write an `OnPost` method on the page model eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/da1?view=aspnetcore-5.0#review-concurrency-exception-handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know how to use the form method to post value into the MVC controller , you could understand what is MVC.

MVC means model view and controller.

MVC is build based on the controller. Each controller will contains a lot of action method.

Each method will contains its own view.

Each view will have its own model.

In asp.net core MVC we normally use form tag helper to post the request to backend MVC controller.

For example:

The MVC Home controller contains a method named the home and the post method test

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Test(int  i) {

        return Ok();
    }
```

If I want to post the i parameter to the backend, I should modify the View to add below codes:

```
<form asp-action="test" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
    <input id="test" name="i" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="test" />

</form>
```

If you click the button, it will post the input i's value to the backend test method. Like below:

[image]

Besides, the Lorem Lpsum generator seems is build for ASP.NET MVC not asp.net core. This may not work inside asp.net 5/ asp.net core.

Comment: If you feel my reply has helped you, please mark it as answer. So that other folks who faces the same issue could find the answer more easily. Thank you.