# Printing valid string array in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, model, lorem-ipsum

This question is partially a continuity from my previous question. I am really sorry for misusing the questioning privilege that I am granted with, but I thought I got the idea of how to navigate around MVC, but apparently not. I have the feeling that I am really close to the ending, but not sure why my code is not printing correctly.

Previous Question: [How do I use post method to display a content in ASP.net core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68553712/how-do-i-use-post-method-to-display-a-content-in-asp-net-core-mvc)

From the answer from that question, and reference to other videos found on the internet, I made a new controller, and class for the Lorem Ipsum pages:

[image: folders of my project]

So from the new controller, the new class and the layout page (where I get my user inputs):

LOSx.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Lorem Ipsum Generator";
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}



<style>
    body {
        /* Margin bottom by footer height */
        margin-bottom: 60px;
        font-family: Kalam, cursive;
    }

    nav {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #a8e6cf, #dcedc1, #ffd3b6, #ffaaa5, #ff8b94);
        background-size: 200% 200%;
        animation: rainbow 10s alternate infinite;
    }

    .JK {
        padding: 15px 25px;
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #04AA6D;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 15px;
        box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
    }

        .JK:hover {
            background-color: #3e8e41
        }

        .JK:active {
            background-color: #3e8e41;
            box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
            transform: translateY(4px);
        }
</style>

<html>
<body class="text-center">
    <form action="GetLos" method="post">
        <h1 style="font-size:26px;">Lorem Ipsum Generator</h1>
        <p>At this page, You will get to generate Lorem Ipsum text, at your desired size and format. Enjoy!</p>
        <p>Enter Number of words to generate: <input name="wordx" type="text" value="10" /></p>
        <p>Enter Number of sentences to generate: <input name="senX" type="text" value="3" /></p>
        <p>Enter Number of paragraphs to generate: <input name="parax" type="text" value="2" /></p>
        <p>Include Data and time at the end of the list? (Proxy is allowed!)  <input type="radio" name="DtY" />Yes    <input type="radio" name="DtN" checked="checked" />No</p>
        <p>If you have selected the option "Yes", Please choose a specific time and date: <input type="datetime-local" name="datetimex" /></p>
        <p>Do you want the generator to start with "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" (Check the box, only if you want): <input type="checkbox" id="startx" />Yes</p>
        <p><input type="submit" class="JK" value="Generate!" /></p>
        <p></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

LotIpsController.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Project_Divinity.Models;

namespace Project_Divinity.Controllers
{
    public class LorIpsController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult LOSx()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetLos(int wordx, int parax, bool DtY, bool DtN, string datetimex, bool startx, int senX, string[] LorX)
        {
            LorIps Fx = new LorIps
            {
                senX = senX,
                wordx = wordx,
                DtN = DtN,
                DtY = DtY,
                datetimex = datetimex,
                parax = parax,
                startx = startx,
                LorX = LoremNET.Lorem.Paragraphs(wordx, senX, parax).ToArray()
        };

            return View(Fx);
        }
    }
}
```

LorIps.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project_Divinity.Models
{
    public class LorIps
    {
        public int senX { get; set; }
        public int wordx { get; set; }
        public int parax { get; set; }
        public bool DtY { get; set; }
        public bool DtN { get; set; }
        public string datetimex { get; set; }
        public bool startx { get; set; }
        public string[] LorX { get; set; }
    }
}
```

GetLos.cshtml:

```
@model Project_Divinity.Models.LorIps;

    <style>
        body {
            /* Margin bottom by footer height */
            margin-bottom: 60px;
            font-family: Kalam, cursive;
            text-align:center;
        }

        nav {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            position: absolute;
            background: linear-gradient(135deg, #a8e6cf, #dcedc1, #ffd3b6, #ffaaa5, #ff8b94);
            background-size: 200% 200%;
            animation: rainbow 10s alternate infinite;
        }
    </style>

<html>
<body>
    <h1>Hi</h1>
    <div>
        <p>@Model.LorX</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using a Lorem generator found on Github: https://github.com/dochoffiday/Lorem.NET
I followed the given example on github, but am not able to print the requested lorem ipsum paragraph. What am I doing wrong?

Currently, if I click on generate, the redirections all work, but the result is:

[image: Current Result of my code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the variable defined as an array which by default you need to use a loop to access and display the data.

`public string[] LorX { get; set; }`

In view you need to do something like:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.LorX.Count(); i++)
{
    <p>@Model.LorX[i]</p>
}
```

For the non-array variables you can display them like you did: `@Model.VariableName`.

Comment: so in my GetLos.cshtml, I'll have to add a new `<script>` part and add the above stated function? I tried it in both with and without the `<script>` part, its resulting in error, that is saying that 'i' is not found in this context.

Comment: You need to replace the current `<p>@Model.LorX</p>` with the `for` loop.

Comment: Damnnn, it worked. :) now i've just gotta work on the remaining parts of the program. yaay